# How do you use inline TypeScript Annotations for Regular JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, annotations, visual-studio-code

In VSCode you can now utilize [type checking for normal JavaScript files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking). There have been times I would like to annotate the type of a variable or parameters on a method or function so that I can have better auto complete.

How can you annotate the types inline for javascript so that you can benefit from VSCode's type checks and auto complete?

### Example

```
let classes = { class1, class2, myClass };
// annotate here so it recognizes MyClass
const myClass = classes.myClass;
// hoping that someFunction or someProperty would autocomplete on myClass
myClass.someFunction();
myClass.someProperty;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no inline TypeScript annotations when using plain JavaScript.

But you can use **JSDoc** to annotate your JavaScript. TypeScript will pick up on these typings so you can fully benefit from the type checking system that VSCode has implemented for normal JavaScript files.

### Example

```
let classes = { class1, class2, myClass };
/** @type {MyClass} */
const myClass = classes.myClass;
// Now MyClass methods and properties will autocomplete
myClass.someFunction();
myClass.someProperty;
```

### Reference

Here's a reference for how to annotate functions and variables using JSDoc.

http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html